# issue with gzip input file with size > 64 MB

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am running a Hadoop streaming job, it has only mappers, no reducers. I am giving this job 4 input files which are all gzipped to make sure that each input file goes to one mapper. Two gzipped input files have size less than 64 MB, whereas two other gzipped input files have size greater than 64MB. Job runs for a long time nearly 40 min and then fails saying "Error: # of failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit." Normally the job should not take more than 1 min, not sure why it went on for 40 min

When I check the output directory I see that the output is generated for two gzipped input files with size < 64 MB and output is not generated for gzipped input files with size > 64 MB.

Has anybody seen such a behaviour?

I see following messages when the job is launched (I dont see this if I pass smaller size files ( < 64 MB) as input to the job)

12/02/06 10:39:10 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
12/02/06 10:39:10 INFO net.NetworkTopology: Adding a new node: /10.209.191.0/10.209.191.57:1004
12/02/06 10:39:10 INFO net.NetworkTopology: Adding a new node: /10.209.191.0/10.209.191.50:1004
12/02/06 10:39:10 INFO net.NetworkTopology: Adding a new node: /10.209.186.0/10.209.186.28:1004
12/02/06 10:39:10 INFO net.NetworkTopology: Adding a new node: /10.209.188.0/10.209.188.48:1004
12/02/06 10:39:10 INFO net.NetworkTopology: Adding a new node: /10.209.185.0/10.209.185.50:1004
12/02/06 10:39:10 INFO net.NetworkTopology: Adding a new node: /10.209.188.0/10.209.188.35:1004

Answer (score 0):

In case you have defined your own derivative of FileInputFormat then I suspect you ran into this bug:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-2094

If you have then I recommend copying the implementation of the isSplitable method from TextInputFormat into your own class.

Comment: No I did not define my own InputFormat. My program is in C++ and I am using hadoop streaming which has a default InputFormat of TextInputFormat.